# "ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT" error to d3.json method

Tags: javascript, d3.js, httpserver

I am trying to make a request to a `json` file, parse through it and return the `json` data as valid javascript using using the `d3.json` method. Both chrome and `firefox` give me the an error.

I started a local server on `port 8080` using the http-server node module to work over http and not the file system for the `d3.json` method to work but my request is unsuccessful. I have tried turning off caching and changing the `port to 8010` to no avail.

To set up `http-server` node module I ran the following code in my gitbash terminal:

```
npm install -g http-server
```

To start my server I ran the following code while in the directory where my index.html file is:

```
http-server
```

To disable the cache and change the port I ran the following code in my terminal:

```
http-server -c-1 -p 8010
```

To request the json data I ran the following code:

```
d3.json('./countries.json', function(error, data) {
    if(error) throw error;

    console.log("DATA", data);
});
```

I expect to get back an object with an array of data,

> instead the chrome page says localhost sent an invalid response
>   (ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT) and the firefox page says Corrupted Content
>   Error.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56364464/http-server-with-localhost3000-gives-err-invalid-redirect/57536943#57536943