# http-server with localhost:3000 gives ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

Tags: node.js, windows

I have installed http-server using the following command:

`npm i -g http-server`

Upon running the server I get the response saying `Running on 127.0.0.1:8080`

My call looks like this:

`http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -c-1`

If I go to `127.0.0.1:8080` or `10.1.1.72:8080` I get:

`This page is not working.`

`127.0.0.1:8080 sent an invalid response`

`ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT`

I have googled and searched everywhere with no answer as to what actually solves this. I'm not using XAMPP or IIS just a blank node server.

`Node.js: 11.12.0`

`npm: 6.7.0`

`OS: Windows 10`

I have checked my host files, there is nothing relevant there. I have no idea what would be causing this. I don't use .htaccess files or Web.config files either.

**Notes**

If I go to `localhost:8080/index.html` I can get to my app. This isn't supposed to work like that though.

Comment: This was a bug in http-server which has been fixed. Running `npm i -g http-server` again should solve the issue!

Answer (score 20):

Try downgrading the http-server version as the latest version (0.10.0 and 0.11.0) is causing issue due to ecstatic (3.3.2).

Try uninstalling the current http-server version and then try to install 0.9.0 or older version

Uninstall

```
 npm uninstall -g http-server
```

Install

```
npm install http-server@0.9.0
```

Answer (score 9):

This is still an open issue with http-server, which is supposedly caused by the latest version of one http-server's dependencies called ecstatic:

https://github.com/http-party/http-server/issues/525

There are three workarounds for this at the point:

1. Point the browser to localhost:8080/index.html instead of just http://localhost:8080.
2. Downgrade your http-server version to 0.9 from 10.0

   npm uninstall -g http-server
    npm install http-server@0.9.0
3. Open package.json file under the http-server module and downgrade ecstatic dependency
   to 3.3.1 (found under 'dependencies' key).

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact same problem. Just installed both node and http-server globally. run `http-server` and it gives me the following error when accessing localhost:8080:

> "ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT"

If I try to access the `index.html page`, it works. It doesn't even show directories listing, even with `-d` in the command line.

I got something, though: installing an older version of `http-server` and it loads the `index.html` automagically :)

This was the command/version: `npm install -g http-server@0.8.5`
Anything newer (0.9.0+) and it breaks again.

**Edit:**

Even then, it will only work on sub-folders, not on the root. For example:

http://localhost:8080/mypage/ will load index.html automatically.

http://localhost:8080/ won't

Comment: And out of the blue its now working even from the root folder for me.
Try running with this:
'http-server ./ -c-1'

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in version 0.12.0, make sure you're upgraded by running

```
npm install --global http-server
```

If you use `npx http-server` it should use the latest version automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I changed http-server version 0.10.0 to 0.8.5 in the package.json file and it worked for me. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

pass url "0.0.0.0" when you are creating server and then try.

Comment: This isn't very helpful as I have already tried this, and it hasn't worked.

Comment: It's not necessary as this is not something that is code based. It is an error administratively