# ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT when running http-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpserver

I use [http-server](https://github.com/http-party/http-server) in my project

#### my system environment:

- `http-server` version is `^0.10.0`
- `OS` is `windows 10`

when run `http-server` return this for me

> This page isn’t working
>
> 127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.
>
> ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56364464/http-server-with-localhost3000-gives-err-invalid-redirect/57536943#57536943

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downgrading `http-server` to `0.9.0` version and fixed for me.